# How to generate advance XML from Postgres

Tags: xml, postgresql, soap

How can I generate an XML similar to this in Postgres? the enrollment date, gender and study identifier will come from a query in the database.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://openclinica.org/ws/studySubject/v1" xmlns:bean="http://openclinica.org/ws/beans">
   <soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"
 xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-27777511"
 xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Username>userName</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password>someHashedPassword/wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:createRequest>
         <v1:studySubject>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bean:label>CBID01</bean:label>
            <bean:enrollmentDate>2016-10-28</bean:enrollmentDate>
            <bean:subject>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bean:gender>f</bean:gender>
            </bean:subject>
            <bean:studyRef>
               <bean:identifier>Clinical_AutoID</bean:identifier>
            </bean:studyRef>
         </v1:studySubject>
      </v1:createRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a pre-built way to do this, but the following guide may be of some use. https://www.treshna.com/postgresql-and-soap-xpath/. Do you specifically need to generate a Soap envelope, or just some XML with a similar structure?

Comment: I just need to generate similar structure

Comment: Can you provide a mock up of the structure you're lookign to create? The problem with the example you have given is that a soap envelope is a pretty specific structure. Do you need the password, username tokens etc? If you can create an example that is closer to what you need, it will be easier to advise.

Comment: This is the structure I need to create, the password and username would be the real ones, but it would never change. So I can create the xml using them as fixed values. Now, the label and enrollmentDate data would come from a table in postgres (they come from same table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to generate the XML file. But if anyone knows a more elegant approach, please let me know.
PS: I eliminated the label field, because the system will auto generate one.

```
select xmlelement(name "soapenv:Envelope", 
        xmlattributes('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "xmlns:soapenv",
                 'http://openclinica.org/ws/studySubject/v1' AS "xmlns:v1",
                 'http://openclinica.org/ws/beans' AS "xmlns:bean"), 
        xmlelement(name "soapenv:Header", 
            xmlelement(name "wsse:Security", 
                xmlattributes(1 AS "soapenv:mustUnderstand", 
                    'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' AS "xmlns:wsse"),
                xmlelement(name "wsse:UsernameToken",
                        xmlattributes('UsernameToken-27777511' AS "wsu:Id",
                            'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd' AS "xmlns:wsu"),
                xmlelement(name "wsse:Username", 'userName'),
                xmlelement(name "wsse:Password",'someHashedPassword')))),
            xmlelement(name "soapenv:Body",
            xmlelement(name "v1:createRequest",
                xmlelement(name "v1:studySubject",
                    xmlelement(name "bean:enrollmentDate", '2016-10-28'),
                    xmlelement(name "bean:subject",
                        xmlelement( name "bean:gender", 'f')),
                    xmlelement(name "bean:studyRef",
                        xmlelement(name "bean:identifier", 'Clinical_AutoID'))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: If you need this to be just postgres, I'm not sure there's a more elegant way. I've used a similar approach before on Oracle. If you were to write a shell script to generate the XML populating the various fields using SQL, it would be neater overall, but the result woudl be the same.